# Changing dimensionality for matplotlib image

Tags: matplotlib, deep-learning, keras

I am using `scipy.misc.imread` for my image loading and for my keras model I have to change the shape from `(3, 224, 224)` to `(224, 224, 3)`. I have been using `numpy.reshape` to acomplish this, but I am not sure that it actually works.

So i tried plotting the resulting image and `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` does not work for the new shape.

Is there any way to plot the resulting image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your image is `im`. Use the following code:

```
im = im.transpose((1, 2, 0))
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(im)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reshaping is dangerous as it would mix the image's channels.

Instead, you need to roll the first axis to the back, leaving the other two as they are. Suppose `im` is your image of shape (3, 224, 224), then the rolling can be accomplished by [`numpy.rollaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html#numpy.rollaxis)

```
new_im = numpy.rollaxis(im,0, start=3)
```

such that `new_im.shape` is `(224, 224, 3)`. This array should be plottable using `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()`